# How can I get my JavaScript function to listen to events and show in my HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, selector

I wanted to practice vanilla JavaScript fundamentals, and I can't see why my `startGame()` function isn't defined. Probably missing something basic.

```
      <button
        id="start-btn"
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onclick="startGame()"
      >
        Start
      </button>
```

Here's the script and markup:

```js
// Get references to the form inputs and start button
const usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
const roundsInput = document.getElementById("rounds");
const puzzlesPerRoundInput = document.getElementById("puzzles-per-round");
const maxDigitsInput = document.getElementById("max-digits");
const timeBetweenChallengesInput = document.getElementById("time-between-challenges");
const additionCheckbox = document.getElementById("addition-checkbox");
const subtractionCheckbox = document.getElementById("subtraction-checkbox");
const multiplicationCheckbox = document.getElementById("multiplication-checkbox");
const divisionCheckbox = document.getElementById("division-checkbox");
const startBtn = document.getElementById("start-btn");

// Add a click event listener to the start button
startBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame);
// Get the values from the form inputs
const username = usernameInput.value;
const rounds = parseInt(roundsInput.value);
const puzzlesPerRound = parseInt(puzzlesPerRoundInput.value);
const maxDigits = parseInt(maxDigitsInput.value);
const timeBetweenChallenges = parseFloat(timeBetweenChallengesInput.value);
const additionChecked = additionCheckbox.checked;
const subtractionChecked = subtractionCheckbox.checked;
const multiplicationChecked = multiplicationCheckbox.checked;
const divisionChecked = divisionCheckbox.checked;

// Validate the form inputs
if (isNaN(rounds) || isNaN(puzzlesPerRound) || isNaN(maxDigits) || isNaN(timeBetweenChallenges)) {
  alert("Please enter valid values for all fields");
  return;
}


// Initialize the game state
let puzzlesSolved = 0;
let puzzlesTried = 0;
let roundsComplete = 0;
let roundDifficulty = maxDigits / timeBetweenChallenges;
let timePerRound = puzzlesPerRound * timeBetweenChallenges + 60;
let timeLeftover = 200 - timePerRound;


  // Start the game loop
function startGame() {  
  for (let round = 1; round <= rounds; round++) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= puzzlesPerRound; i++) {
      // Start the countdown timer for the current puzzle
      let timeLeft = timePerRound;
      let countdownInterval = setInterval(function() {
        timeLeft -= 1;
        if (timeLeft <= 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownInterval);
          // Handle time's up
          console.log('Time for round is up!')
          window.removeEventListener("keydown", inputHandler);
        } else {
          // Update the countdown display
          // TODO: display timeLeft
          timeLeftSpan.textContent = timeLeft;
        }
      }, 1000);

      // Generate a random pair of numbers and pick an operation
      let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 ** maxDigits - 1) + 1);
      let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 ** maxDigits - 1) + 1);
      
        let operation;
  if (additionChecked) {
    operation = "+";
  } else if (subtractionChecked) {
    operation = "-";
    // Make sure result is non-negative
    if (num2 > num1) {
      [num1, num2] = [num2, num1];
    }
  } else if (multiplicationChecked) {
    operation = "*";
  } else if (divisionChecked) {
    operation = "/";
    // Make sure quotient is an integer
    if (num2 > num1) {
        num1 = num2 * Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 ** (maxDigits - 1) - 1) + 1);
    }
  }

  // Calculate the expected result
  let result = eval(num1 + operation + num2);

  // Flash the numbers to the user
  notification.textContent = `${num1} ${operation} ${num2}`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    notification.textContent = "";
  }, timeBetweenChallenges * 1000);

  // Listen for the user's input
  let userInput = "";
  let inputHandler = (e) => {
    userInput += e.key;
    notification.textContent = userInput;
  };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", inputHandler);

  // Wait for the user to input their answer or for the time to run out
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    timeLeft -= 1;
    timeLeftSpan.textContent = timeLeft;
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      notification.textContent = "";
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", inputHandler);
      puzzlesTried += 1;
      displayResults();
    }
    if (userInput === result.toString()) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", inputHandler);
      puzzlesSolved += 1;
      puzzlesTried += 1;
      displayResults();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

  }
}

// Function to display results in the bottom area
function displayResults() {
  puzzlesSolvedSpan.textContent = puzzlesSolved;
  puzzlesTriedSpan.textContent = puzzlesTried;
  timeLeftSpan.textContent = timeLeft;
  roundDifficultySpan.textContent = roundDifficulty.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Anzan Flash</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
  <script src="flashAnzan.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">

  <div class="container mx-auto my-8">
    <!-- Top notifications area -->
    <div class="flex justify-center mb-8">
      <div id="notification" class="w-1/2 bg-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Middle input area -->
    <div class="flex justify-center mb-8">
      <form class="w-1/2 bg-white p-4 rounded-md shadow-md">
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="username">
            Username
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="username"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your username">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="rounds">
            Rounds
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="rounds"
            type="number"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            placeholder="Enter number of rounds">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="puzzles-per-round">
            Puzzles per Round
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="puzzles-per-round"
            type="number"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            placeholder="Enter number of puzzles per round">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="max-digits">
            Max Digits
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="max-digits"
            type="number"
            min="1"
            max="4"
            placeholder="Enter max digits for puzzles">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" for="time-between-challenges">
            Time Between Challenges (seconds)
          </label>
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="time-between-challenges"
            type="number"
            min="0.5"
            max="10"
            onchange="maxDigits = this.value"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="my-4">
        <label class="flex items-center">
          <input
            id="addition-checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
            name="addition"
            value="addition"
            checked
            onchange="addition = this.checked"
          >
          <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Addition</span>
        </label>
        <label class="flex items-center">
          <input
            id="subtraction-checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
            name="subtraction"
            value="subtraction"
            onchange="subtraction = this.checked"
          >
          <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Subtraction</span>
        </label>
        <label class="flex items-center">
          <input
            id="multiplication-checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
            name="multiplication"
            value="multiplication"
            onchange="multiplication = this.checked"
          >
          <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Multiplication</span>
        </label>
        <label class="flex items-center">
          <input
            id="division-checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600"
            name="division"
            value="division"
            onchange="division = this.checked"
          >
          <span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Division</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button
        id="start-btn"
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onclick="startGame()"
      >
        Start
      </button>
    
    
    
    <div id="game-container" class="hidden">
      <div class="text-center text-xl font-bold my-4" id="challenge-timer">
        Time: <span id="time"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center my-4">
        <div class="mx-4">
          <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold text-xl" id="num1"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-4">
          <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold text-xl" id="operator"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-4">
          <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold text-xl" id="num2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-4">
          <span class="text-gray-700 font-bold text-xl">=</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-4">
          <input
            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="user-answer"
            type="number"
            onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) checkAnswer()"
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="flex items-center justify-center mt-4">
        <button
          id="start-btn"
          class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        >
          Starting
        </button>
      </div> -->
      
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom results area -->
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-200 py-4 px-6">
        <div class="flex-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
          Time Left: <span id="time-left"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-1 text-sm text-gray-600 text-center">
          Difficulty: <span id="round-difficulty"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-1 text-sm text-gray-600 text-right">
          Solved/Tried: <span id="puzzles-solved"></span>/<span id="puzzles-tried"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update: I've change the callback issue, and the addEventListener issue, but when I click the 'Submit' button, I still just get a page refresh, and no onpage elements have been updated w/script results.

Comment: Make up your mind, whether you want to use `onclick` in the HTML code, _or_ `addEventListener`.

Comment: You currently have `function startGame()` wrapped inside of your addEventListener click handler callback function - so it won't exist before the first click happens (and probably not in the right scope then either), so the browser does not find the function when it parsey your onclick attribute.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
You can use this method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).